# MySQL: Order by hierarchy without recursion in programming

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have a table with following structure and sample values-

**ls_navigator**

```
+----+------------------+-----------+
| id | title            | parent_id |
+----+------------------+-----------+
|  1 | English Language |      NULL |
|  2 | ICT              |      NULL |
|  3 | Class IX         |      NULL |
|  4 | Class X          |      NULL |
|  5 | Class XI         |      NULL |
|  6 | Class XII        |      NULL |
|  7 | Reading          |         1 |
|  8 | Writing          |         1 |
|  9 | Speaking         |         1 |
| 10 | Listening        |         1 |
| 11 | abc              |         7 |
| 12 | xyz              |         7 |
| 13 | asdfg            |        12 |
| 14 | qwert            |         8 |
+----+------------------+-----------+
```

Here `parent_id` indicates the parent element of the same table. Now I want this data to be selected such a way so the child rows come after the parent row as the following result.

```
+----+------------------+-----------+
| id | title            | parent_id |
+----+------------------+-----------+
|  1 | English Language |      NULL |
|  7 | Reading          |         1 |
| 11 | abc              |         7 |
| 12 | xyz              |         7 |
| 13 | asdfg            |        12 |
|  8 | Writing          |         1 |
| 14 | qwert            |         8 |
|  9 | Speaking         |         1 |
| 10 | Listening        |         1 |
|  2 | ICT              |      NULL |
|  3 | Class IX         |      NULL |
|  4 | Class X          |      NULL |
|  5 | Class XI         |      NULL |
|  6 | Class XII        |      NULL |
+----+------------------+-----------+
```

I know it can be done from the programming end using recursion, but I was trying to generate a single query to get such a result.

**I tried** like this, but it returns wrong order and duplicate data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (SELECT
        *,
        LPAD(parent_id, 3, '0') AS id1
      FROM ls_navigator

      UNION

      SELECT
        *,
        LPAD(id, 3, '0') AS id1
      FROM ls_navigator
     ) AS t
WHERE id1 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id1;
```

This **PHP** code snippet does as expected in my case-

```
private function get_content_children($parent_id = null, $hyphen = '')
{
    if ($parent_id === null) $where = "parent_id is null";
    else $where = "parent_id = $parent_id";

    $resData = [];

    $q = $this->db->get_where("ls_contents", $where);
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = $q->result();
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $row->hypen = $hyphen;
            $resData[] = $row;
            $resData = array_merge($resData, $this->get_content_children($row->id, $hyphen . ' -'));
        }
    }
    return $resData;
}
```

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT *` is oxymoronic

Comment: I applied it just to omit duplicate data which is just one try out of hundreds.